# Wrote a pandas DF with a column with lists to a file, how to read it back?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe with one of the columns populated by lists, like this:

```
    c1    c2

0  "asd"  ["el1", "el2"]

1  "sdf"  ["el1", "el3", "el5"]
```

Writing this to a csv through the `to_csv` function naturally outputs the lists as strings. When I read the file again via `read_csv`, for example, the first list is read as `"[el1, el2]"` instead of the intended `["el1", "el2"]`. So if I run the `split` command, the intended output is `"el1", "el2"` but instead what I get is `"[", "e", "l", "1", ",", "e", "l", "2", "]"`.

How do I circumvent this? How do I cleanly write and read list columns of a pandas dataframe?

Comment: A better suggestion is to not write them as columns of lists in the first place. Actually, don't even have columns of lists.

Comment: @cs95: What alternative would you suggest, then? Let's say corresponding to each row, I'm required to maintain a set of strings (the set could be large and have variable length from row to row), what would be your recommended way to go about it?

Comment: Depends on your data but you could probably factorize your strings and store them in a sparse format or at the very least have each string occupy it's own column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert columns filled by lists with `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast

df['c2'] = df['c2'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
print (df)
    c1               c2
0  asd       [el1, el2]
1  sdf  [el1, el3, el5]
```

Another idea is use `converters` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) with lambda function and `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
from io import StringIO

temp="""c1;c2
"asd";["el1", "el2"]
"sdf";["el1", "el3", "el5"]"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
con = lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x)
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep=';', converters = {'c2':con})

print (df)
    c1               c2
0  asd       [el1, el2]
1  sdf  [el1, el3, el5]
```

---

If write data to csv, always are conveterted to strings, for avoid it is possible use another formats, e.g. pickle and use [`DataFrame.to_pickle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html) with [`read_pickle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_pickle.html):

```
df.to_pickle('file.pkl')

df = pd.read_pickle('file.pkl')
print (df)
    c1               c2
0  asd       [el1, el2]
1  sdf  [el1, el3, el5]
```

Comment: Interesting! So if pickle format is so versatile, why isn't it used more often than csv? Any caveats?

Comment: @ShirishKulhari - hmmm, maybe not so easy check data by any text editor, also not sure if not necessary some libs for linux/wins/mac ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.strip("[]")` to get rid of the brackets, and then `.split()` on the commas:

```py
>>> list("[el1,el2,el3]".strip("[]").split(","))
["el1", "el2", "el3"]
```

I'm not sure if there is a better generic way to deal with variable length lists in pandas though.